# GridViews In multiple columns

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have this code written using asp and I'm using Bootstrap. I want to know how to display the grid view in multiple columns next to each other. Here is the aspx code.
[Here is the aspx code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xboz7.png)

And Here is The output when I used column class.
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jeTKl.jpg)

Comment: Hi @user15602549, please attach your code as snippet instead of image. Thank you. For your reference: [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Just add more boundfield/templatefields within the same Columns tag (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield?view=netframework-4.8)